Bad shading on rounder corner


I am trying to make a roof of a car. And there is a bump  (when shade smooth is turned on) in the area of the vertex connecting three faces, although subdivision surface smoothed it out. Is there a way to get rid of this problem?

This has to do with normals. Dunno if it should be that pointy given how close those vertices are to each other relative to the rest of the mesh, or not. Check that you do not have any custom split normals data on the mesh, and that the crease values for the vertices around that point are all zero.
